# Alter Database in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create a new stored procedure to execute an `Alter Database` command to modify the database Service Tiers.

So, I've tried to create the stored procedure but It doesn't work and it returns an error

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Could someone tell me how can I do this? Or where is the syntax error?
I've run this one out of any stored procedure and it worked.

Thanks in advance.

```
create procedure spChangeTiersDB 
    @MaxSize varchar(8), 
    @Edition varchar(20), 
    @Service varchar(5)
as
begin
     ALTER DATABASE DB_Name 
     MODIFY (
     MAXSIZE = @MaxSize,  
     EDITION = @Edition,
     SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = @Service)
end
```

Comment: Azure databases restrict what you can do: you may be running into one of these restrictions. Certainly, MaxSize sounds like one of the things that they want to manage, not you (you partly pay by the size).

Comment: Ok, I'm agree with you, the thing is that I can change those things in my SQL Server Management Studio. That means that could have something unattended to make those changes like stored procedures, functions, etc.

Comment: Not everything that you can do with a local SQL database can be done with an Azure one. I'm pretty sure MaxSize will be one.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot parameterize `ALTER DATABASE` statements

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/578d87fa-9939-4cb0-bb72-e37cee8abf25/can-i-pass-parameter-to-an-alter-database-command

As suggested on the MSDN forum link, use Dynamic SQL instead

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spChangeDBtier 
@MaxSize VARCHAR(10),@Edition VARCHAR(10),@Service VARCHAR(10) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = CONCAT('ALTER DATABASE dbname MODIFY ( MAXSIZE =',@MaxSize,'GB, Edition = ''',@Edition,''',SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ''',@Service,''')')
EXEC(@SQL)
END
```

Sample execution:

```
spChangeDBtier '500','PREMIUM','P1'
```

Comment: This neither can be with Dynamic SQL, because the result returns an error "Incorrect syntax near '('.". So, I can't implement that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can't do those changes with something unattended like stored procedures, functions, etc. So, I've made something in C# to change from the server. That's my answer at the moment. If someone else has the same problem here is the code to help.

```
    public static bool ChangeDBTier(string DbName, string MaxSize, string Edition, string Service)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                String sqlCommandText = @"ALTER DATABASE " + DbName + " MODIFY (MAXSIZE = " + MaxSize + ", EDITION = '" + Edition + "', SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = '" + Service + "')";
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, con);
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check the update to my answer, you absolutely can do it in a SP

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE #spChangeDBtier 
 @MaxSize VARCHAR(10),@Edition VARCHAR(10),@Service VARCHAR(10) AS BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL  NVARCHAR(MAX)
set @sql = 'alter database test modify(maxsize = '+ @MaxSize + ', edition = ''' + @MaxSize + ''' , service_objective = ''' + @MaxSize + ''')' 
EXEC @SQL
END

You can always specify max size but I don't think that is needed as size won't impact billing significantly